# Jänich's Open Set axioms and definitions imply that the empty set *and* topological space $X$ are both open and closed; is this correct?

Tags: general-topology

Open Set definition of a Topological Space, from Jänich's *Topology*:

[image: Topological space axioms]
From definition (1) for some set $A \subset X$: $$X \setminus A \text{ is open} \implies A \text{ is closed}$$

Further, from Axiom 3, $\emptyset$ and $X$ are both open. So we have that

$$X \setminus \emptyset = X \text{ is open} \\ 
\text{and} \\ 
X \setminus X = \emptyset \text{ is open}$$

This implies that $\emptyset$ and $X$ are both *open* and *closed*. Is this correct to say?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you Brian; I tried searching "is topological space both open and closed" and was struggling to find answers.

Comment: You’re welcome!

Comment: sometimes such sets are called "clopen"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in **any** topological space $(X, \mathcal{O})$, $\emptyset$ and $X$ are open and also closed. (such sets are often called "clopen"). It's unfortunate that this is linguistically paradoxical, and can be a case for confusion for beginning students. A set can be both open and closed (or neither, as is often the case). In the discrete topology (i.e. $\mathcal{O}=\mathscr{P}(X)$) *every* subset is open and closed.

Some terminology around this:
A space $X$ where $\emptyset$ and $X$ are the *only* clopen sets is called *connected*. A space where every subset is open or closed (or both) is called a *door space*. A space where every open subset is the union of clopen subsets is called *zero-dimensional*. A space where every open subset is also closed (and vice versa) is called a *partition space*.

Answer (score 1):

The answer appears to just simply be yes. I was thrown off by the idea of being both open and closed (this is my first time studying topology), but it seems that this is just natural to the discipline.

Thank you Brian M. Scott!

See [Are $\emptyset$ and $X$ closed, open or clopen?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128323/are-emptyset-and-x-closed-open-or-clopen?rq=1) for a more thorough discussion.