# What is an example of an open set A which we can write it in the form of a Cartesian product of two sets $B\times C$? (B and C not necessarily open)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces, open-map

I know each open set not necessarily be the cartesian product of two open sets. but I want an example for this equation.
Please help me.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sorry. What is an example of an open set A which we can write it in the form of a Cartesian product of two sets B and C? (B and C not necessarily be open)

Comment: Take one of the sets to be empty.

Comment: If you start with open sets $B,C$ then $B\times C$ will be open (in the appropriate topology). Unless $B,C$ are both open, their product can't be open.

Comment: I think empty is an open set. according to [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/447170/why-is-empty-set-an-open-set).

Comment: To be honest, I wanna prove "Each open set is not a Cartesian product of two open sets.". How can I prove it? @GerryMyerson

Comment: To begin with, if $B$ is open in the topological space $X$, and $C$ is open in the topological space $Y$, then you have to tell us how you are defining a topology on $X\times Y$, in terms of the topologies on $X$ and on $Y$.

Comment: So, what's your definition, Iman? (lman?)

Comment: Actually Iman (with i). It's an Arabic name. It means believing in something like a god or a person. @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$B = (0,1)$$
$$C = (0,1)$$
$$A = B \times C = (0,1) \times (0,1)$$

It is (hopefully) clear that $B$ and $C$ are both open sets, since they are open intervals. To see why $A$ is open, show that every point in $A$ is an interior point.

**Hint:** Assume that arbitrary point in $A$ is $p = (x,y)$ where both $x$ and $y$ are in $(0,1)$. Now, try to find a ball around $p$ such that the whole ball is contained in $A$.

**To answer your question in comments (whether every open set is cartesian product of two open sets):**

No. For a simple counterexample, consider a open disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Do you see why this set cannot be Cartesian product of two open intervals in $\mathbb{R}$?